# library importing issues in pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I'm doing a project on opencv python which is based on downloaded source code from the internet. When I run the code, this error occurs

```
C:\Users\Udara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/Udara/Desktop/7777/people-counting-opencv/people_counter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Udara/Desktop/7777/people-counting-opencv/people_counter.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyimagesearch.centroidtracker import CentroidTracker
  File "C:\Users\Udara\Desktop\7777\people-counting-opencv\pyimagesearch\centroidtracker.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ordereddict
  File "C:\Users\Udara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\ordereddict.py", line 23, in <module>
    from UserDict import DictMixin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UserDict'
```

Comment: You are missing `UserDict`. It can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/UserDict.py). Place it in your working directory.